# Retrieve child values by date inserted from user in string format

Tags: java, android, sorting, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve child values by date.
The date which exist in firebase is inserted in string datatypes though datepicker of android UI page.

[image]

```
  total_report = new TotalReport();
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Objects.requireNonNull(firebaseAuth.getUid()));
    DatabaseReference dbs = ref.child("Running Report");
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.monthly_info, R.id.monthlyInfo, list);
    dbs.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                total_report = ds.getValue(TotalReport.class);
                list.add(total_report.getUserDate() + "       " + total_report.getUserDistance() + "                       " + total_report.getUserDuration() + "                              " + total_report.getUserPace());
            }
            list_View_month.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

Comment: Sounds like a nice use-case. Can you edit your question to show what you tried already, and where you got stuck? If it is related to filtering the dates, that might be caused by the format in which you store the dates, and I recommend reading my answers here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41553469, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/41553469

Comment: As per my code, it prints all the child values in list but i need the child values by month/week.

Comment: There is no way to get nodes by "month" of "week" with your current data structure. Consider storing them as separate `month` and `week` properties, to simplify querying for them. This kind of data duplication is quite common when using NoSQL databases. If this is new to you, I recommend checking out [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: Is it possible to get child values for a particular month.

Comment: Your current format looks European, with the month in the middle. Firebase only allows prefix matches in filters, so won't be able to find a string in the middle. That why I recommended storing the month and week in separate properties.